# Angular Nativescript http request stalled

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-httpclient

Newbie to NativeScript. I'm working on my first http request, and the request gets "stalled". That's the message in the network tab of the Chrome console when I launch "tns debug android".

The request works in the emulator's browser. The request works in my Angular Web project. The request works when I double-click on the request line in the network tabs.

Could it be some kind of permissions error. In the AndroidManifest I have both:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's specific to any network permissions. Does this happen only with the calls you make to your server or it even happens with any endpoint, may be `http://google.com` for instance?

Comment: Good idea. I found a public testing api at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/. I created a get request using that as the endpoint, and it succeeded. Seems like there is something wrong in the structure of my request.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer. Tweaked the code and found this error:

java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to ... not permitted. I haven't been using https in dev so either I need to use it, or set some flag to cleartextTrafficPermitted=true.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue when using HTTP not HTTPS in dev environment as well.

The above answer is right but just thinking of making it more clear:

Put `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the `application` tag.

Example:

```
<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```